# Using Awk and Condition for catching lines when column of a file contains a position between a given range by another file

Tags: bash, awk, range, multiple-columns

I want to identify the score for each gene
However for this I need to put a condition that identify the score (column $3 Score list) that is in one position between the given range of column $3 and $4 of gene list

**gene List:**

```
chr1    TAS1R1  6615000 6615100
chr1    TAS1R1  6615130 6615200
chr5    TCERG1  145858055   145858216
```

**Score list:**

```
rs79923433 chr1 6615060 0.327009537545002 0.177578086220885
rs4908925 chr1 6615107 0.492182375024342 0.278821401692196
rs114220820 chr1 6615172 0.24581165286421 0.129806066087895
rs925345 chr5 145858100 1.22569136462918 0.744498627741366
```

**What I desire:**

```
chr1    TAS1R1  6615000 6615100 0.327009537545002
chr1    TAS1R1  6615130 6615200 0.24581165286421
chr5    TCERG1  145858055   145858216 1.22569136462918
```

Comment: I tried creating of bash command per position but this is taking too long 

    `for s in `gene_list`; do echo "awk 'BEGIN{" $s "} {if (i<SS3 && f>SS3)    print SS4; else print 99999}' score_list | sort -g | head -n1
    "; done | sed 's/SS/$/g' > script.sh`

And then with each script.sh it searches for whole genome

Comment: I would start by combining the files in order, then we can try the next step: `cat gene_list score_list | sort -k 3 -n >combined_list`.

Comment: Please post your code as part of your Q. It would also help if you show your current output. Good luck.

Comment: You want to append field `$4` from the score list to each line in the gene list where score list field `$3` is between gene list fields `$3` and `$4` on that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {score[$3] = $4; next}
    {
        for (key in score) 
            if ($3 <= key && key <= $4) 
                print $0, score[key]
    }
' score.list gene.list
```

```
chr1    TAS1R1  6615000 6615100 0.327009537545002
chr1    TAS1R1  6615130 6615200 0.24581165286421
chr5    TCERG1  145858055   145858216 1.22569136462918
```

It's not super efficient, since you have to iterate over all the scores for each line of the genes, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank You Jackman It is still better than my previously code 
that was taking too long

Comment: I finished one of the files and I can say that it worked much much better with your command line :)

Thanks @Jackman!

Comment: and if i wonder to do the inverse? printing the 

'rs79923433 chr1 6615060 0.327009537545002 0.177578086220885 TAS1R1'
what changes I will have to do?